Post-apocalyptic music video
In the early to mid 90s, I saw a music video on (United States) MTV or VH1 (back when they still showed music videos) with an intriguing narrative. I only saw it once, but it left a lasting impression. The music wasn't as memorable to me--the contemporary pop/rock of the times.
The storyline is about a man who wakes up after an unexplained Rapture event. He is seemingly the only person left in the world. In the kitchen, the stove is on, and food is burning. On the highway, cars are empty and abandoned. He raids a store, and then, in a fit of conscience, goes back and leaves money on the counter. In the last scene, he's high on a building, contemplating jumping off, when he sees a girl, somewhere far below, dart out of the shadows and then disappear again.
It was pretty high production values, so I'm assuming it was a band with some resources behind it.

You don't need to pre-emptively argue that this is on-topic when it's very clearly on-topic.

@Valorum I just had never seen a music-video question here, but when I saw there was a tag for it, I realized I was on safe ground.  Thanks for the edit.

If it's sci-fi or fantasy, then it's on topic. That even goes for shampoo commercials

I'm assuming USA for this?

@bob1 If it was MTV or VH1 it was most likely USA, I don't know how far they had spread overseas, and if they were, had switched to showing videos produced in that country. (I do recall seeing MTV overseas, but it was still the USA broadcast),

@NJohnny We had MTV (don't know about VH1) in my country from the '90s and a bit earlier I think, though I seem to recall not as a stand-alone channel, more replays of Top-40 hits style content on a local channel. The content was local, UK, and North American, so some variation from the USA broadcast, but whether that included locally produced videos, I don't recall. Though as you note - most likely USA given the subject matter.

@bob1 - early 1990s, living in Amsterdam (Netherlands, not NY), MTV was most definitely on the cable network I had.

could the video be from a movie? ... the description sounds vaguely familiar

@jsotola - Yes, quite possibly. If people have seen movies that fit I'd definitely review them to see if they look familiar.

@jsotola It also felt like it might have been inspired by a movie
